# Will the use of secure protocols such as HTTPS or SFTP eliminate SQL injection and XSS attackes? why?

Tags: security, xss, sql-injection

I am not working with any code I am just trying to get a better understanding of security based around SQL Injection and XSS attacks. My main questions is 'Will the use of HTTPS or SFTP eliminate SQL injection and XSS attacks? If so Why or Why not?

Id appreciate and answer not links as I dont find them useful. Hope you can help
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No these protocols have absolutely nothing to do with database vulnerabilities and non-sanitized user inputs.

SQL Injection attacks occur when user input is processed as part of a SQL statement that has not been sanitized.  That is purged of any potentially malicious content.  This is usually handled via the use of prepared statements.

XSS is similar except it occurs when user input is not sanitized at the user interface level.  Typically this occurs when a developer allows someone to write arbitrary text that can be converted to HTML/Javascript.  You can get around this by HTML encoding elements.

[Cheat sheet for XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)

[Cheat sheet for SQL injection](http://ha.ckers.org/sqlinjection/)

Answer (score 1):

No, because HTTPS and SFTP ensure that evesdroppers are not listening in or tampering with the connection between client and server. SQL injection and XSS attacks originate at the client endpoint so they "start" before either of those protocols has a chance to do anything.